# Splitting gzipped logfiles without storing the ungzipped splits on disk

Tags: linux, gzip, text-files, split

I have a recurring task of splitting a set of large (about 1-2 GiB each) gzipped Apache logfiles into several parts (say chunks of 500K lines). The final files should be gzipped again to limit the disk usage.

On Linux I would normally do:

```
zcat biglogfile.gz | split -l500000
```

The resulting files files will be named xaa, xab, xac, etc 
So I do:

```
gzip x*
```

The effect of this method is that as an intermediate result these *huge* files are temporarily stored on disk. Is there a way to avoid this intermediate disk usage?

Can I (in a way similar to what xargs does) have split pipe the output through a command (like gzip) and recompress the output on the fly? 
Or am I looking in the wrong direction and is there a much better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I would look at implementing split style functionality in a scripting language, where you could write the lines straight into gzipped files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `split --filter` option as explained in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) e.g.

```
zcat biglogfile.gz | split -l500000 --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz'
```

Edit: not aware when `--filter` option was introduced but according to comments, it is not working in `core utils 8.4`.

Comment: Thanks. I think using a feature in split that was designed to do this kind of operation is always better than homegrown code.

Comment: very nice but note that split of coreutils 8.4 does not have a `filter` argumnet

Answer (score 3):

A script like the following might suffice.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use PerlIO::gzip;

$filename = 'out';
$limit = 500000;

$fileno = 1;
$line = 0;

while (<>) {
    if (!$fh || $line >= $limit) { 
        open $fh, '>:gzip', "$filename_$fileno"; 
        $fileno++;
        $line = 0; 
    }
    print $fh $_; $line++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your quick example helped me a lot. With two minor fixes (first line must start with #!/  and after the $fileno++ an additional $line=0 is needed) it worked good enough for my purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I've added those to the script for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

In case people need to keep the 1st row (the header) in each of the pieces

```
zcat bigfile.csv.gz | tail -n +2 | split -l1000000 --filter='{ { zcat bigfile.csv.gz | head -n 1 | gzip; gzip; } > $FILE.gz; };'
```

I know it's a bit clunky. I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

There's [zipsplit](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Zipsplit), but that uses the zip algorithm as opposed to the gzip algorithm.