# How gzip file gets stored in HDFS

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, compression, hdfs, gzip

HDFS storage support compression format to store compressed file. I know that gzip compression doesn't support splinting. Imagine now the file is a gzip-compressed file whose compressed size is 1 GB. Now my question is:

1. How this file will get stored in HDFS (Block size is 64MB)

From this [link](http://comphadoop.weebly.com/) I came to know that The gzip format uses DEFLATE to store the compressed data, and DEFLATE stores data as a series of compressed blocks.

But I couldn't understand it completely and looking for broad explanation.

**More doubts from gzip compressed file:**

2. How many block will be there for this 1GB gzip compressed file.
3. Will it go on multiple datanode ?
4. How replication factor will be applicable for this file ( Hadoop cluster replication factor is 3.)
5. What is `DEFLATE` algorithm?
6. Which algorithm is applied while reading the gzip compressed file?

I am looking here broad and detailed explanation.

Comment: A file in a file system does not have to be contiguous on disk, whether the disk is one physical disk, or many disks in a distributed file system.  The file system divides the file into blocks, which it stores wherever it decides to store it. When an application requests a file, the file system knows the mapping to the blocks and where the blocks are. It sends an I/O request to retrieve them, then the file system pieces the blocks back into the file. This division of large things is kind of the whole point. A distributed system can pool resources to do things a single system couldn't do alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How this file will get stored in HDFS (Block size is 64MB) if splitting does not supported for zip file format?

All DFS blocks will be stored in single Datanode. If your block size is 64 MB and file is 1 GB, the `Datanode` with 16 DFS blocks ( 1 GB / 64 MB = 15.625) will store 1 GB file.

> How many block will be there for this 1GB gzip compressed file.

1 GB / 64 MB = 15.625 ~ 16 DFS blocks

> How replication factor will be applicable for this file ( Hadoop cluster replication factor is 3.)

Same as of any other file. If the file is splittable, no change. If the file is not splittable, Datanodes with required number of blocks will be identified. In this case, 3 datanodes with 16 available DFS blocks.

> What is DEFLATE algorithm?

DELATE is the algorithm to uncompress zipped files of GZIP format.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. if the gzip compressed file gets splitted during the storage on HDFS, then again why it says that gzip doesn't support splitting and why it is processed through single mapper. Can you clarify this too

Comment: Gzip is not splitable and hence one mapper will process  16 blocks of 1 GB file.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630245/hadoop-gzip-compressed-files

Comment: So, we can understand that gzip file are splittable with a sequential series of blocks while storing the data into HDFS. But due to certain limitation in mapReduce it not supporting parallel processing and hence we can say that gzip is not splittable during MapReduce processing. Right ?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly.   Single Mapper has to process all blocks of gzip file.

Comment: I am trying to search more information while processing the gzip file. If you have more reference, can you post it here ?

Comment: This link may help you: http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec

Comment: "All DFS blocks will be stored in single Datanode" - this isn't true unfortunately. HDFS blocks of a multi-block gzip file can be stored on multiple datanodes. They'll indeed will have to be processed by a single mapper, but that mapper will do remote reads to collect all remote blocks before de-compressing.

Answer (score 0):

gzip doesn't support splitting or we say it is unsplittable. In such case the file cannot be processed by multiple map tasks. Also, gzip uses DEFLATE - meaning the compressed file will be splitted into blocks and all of them are stored as contiguous blocks (there won't be any markings telling block beginning - block ending for compressed data). Because no way to identify block beginning and ending, only a single mapper has to process the entire file, regardless of its size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).